# About how many qubits and how many T gates is needed to verify Quantum Money from Knots?

Tags: quantum-money

Dalzell, McArdle, Berta, Bienias, Chen, Gilyén, Hann, Kastoryano, Khabiboulline, Kubica, Salton, Wang, and Brandão have [posted](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.03011) a comprehensive assessment of state-of-the-art end-to-end resources needed for many quantum algorithms.  Often Dalzell *et al.* provide qubit counts and T depths needed to implement various algorithms.  Their analysis suggests that resources may be quite daunting, especially for algorithms admitting "only" a polynomial speedup.

But, has anyone gamed out roughly how many qubits, and how many gates, are required for [Quantum Money from Knots](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5127)? Do we know how complicated a verification circuit would be, to calculate the knot invariant ([Alexander polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_polynomial)) and to apply the Markov chain ([Reidemeister/Cromwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reidemeister_move) moves) in superposition?

We only know knot tables up to about 16 or so crossings; perhaps even a modest number of logical qubits (a couple hundred or so) would be of sufficient security.  However, the verification circuits do intuitively feel intimidating - calculating Alexander polynomials and especially applying knot moves in superposition seem pretty tough with probably very deep (although polynomial) circuits. I'd guess a depth of several millions or more CCNOT (Toffoli) and CSWAP (Fredkin) gates to calculate the Alexander polynomial of such knot diagrams.